# Why Zxing Maui barcode scanner crashes on IOS?

Tags: ios, maui, zxing

I'm using Zxing barcode scanner on an empty project as follows:

XAML :

```
    <ScrollView>
        <VerticalStackLayout
            Spacing="25"
            Padding="30,0"
            VerticalOptions="Center">

            <zxing:CameraBarcodeReaderView x:Name="cameraBarcodeReaderView" />
        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</ContentPage>
```

C#

```
using ZXing.Net.Maui;

namespace CameraTest;

public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    int count = 0;

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        cameraBarcodeReaderView.Options = new BarcodeReaderOptions
        {
            Formats = BarcodeFormats.OneDimensional,
            AutoRotate = true,
            Multiple = true
        };
    }
}
```

MauiProgram.cs

```
using ZXing.Net.Maui;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace CameraTest;

public static class MauiProgram
{
    public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
    {
        var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
        builder
            .UseMauiApp<App>()
            .UseBarcodeReader()
            .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
            {
                fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
                fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
            });

#if DEBUG
        builder.Logging.AddDebug();
#endif

        return builder.Build();
    }
}
```

Info.plist:

```
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app uses barcode scanning to...</string>
```

But when running the app on IPhone 14 iOS 16.4 simulator, I'm getting the following error. By the way, I didn't write a single line of my own code.

What's wrong with the Zxing barcode?

[image]

```
{System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'device')
   at ObjCRuntime.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(String argumentName)
   at ObjCRuntime.NativeObjectExtensions.GetNonNullHandle(INativeObject self, String argumentName)
   at AVFoundation.AVCaptureDeviceInput..ctor(AVCaptureDevice device, NSError& error)
   at ZXing.Net.Maui.CameraManager.UpdateCamera()
   at ZXing.Net.Maui.CameraManager.UpdateCameraLocation(CameraLocation cameraLocation)
   at ZXing.Net.Maui.CameraBarcodeReaderViewHandler.<>c.<.cctor>b__24_1(CameraBarcodeReaderViewHandler handler, ICameraBarcodeReaderView virtualView)
   at Microsoft.Maui.PropertyMapper`2.<>c__DisplayClass5_0[[ZXing.Net.Maui.ICameraBarcodeReaderView, ZXing.Net.Maui, Version=1.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[ZXing.Net.Maui.CameraBarcodeReaderViewHandler, ZXing.Net.Maui, Version=1.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].<Add>b__0(IElementHandler h, IElement v)
   at Microsoft.Maui.PropertyMapper.UpdatePropertyCore(String key, IElementHandler viewHandler, IElement virtualView)
   at Microsoft.Maui.PropertyMapper.UpdateProperties(IElementHandler viewHandler, IElement virtualView)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ElementHandler.SetVirtualView(IElement view)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ViewHandler`2[[ZXing.Net.Maui.ICameraBarcodeReaderView, ZXing.Net.Maui, Version=1.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[UIKit.UIView, Microsoft.iOS, Version=16.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=84e04ff9cfb79065]].SetVirtualView(IView view)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ViewHandler`2[[ZXing.Net.Maui.ICameraBarcodeReaderView, ZXing.Net.Maui, Version=1.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[UIKit.UIView, Microsoft.iOS, Version=16.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=84e04ff9cfb79065]].SetVirtualView(IElement view)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Element.SetHandler(IElementHandler newHandler)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Element.set_Handler(IElementHandler value)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.VisualElement.Microsoft.Maui.IElement.set_Handler(IElementHandler value)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ElementExtensions.ToHandler(IElement view, IMauiContext context)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ElementExtensions.ToPlatform(IElement view, IMauiContext context)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.LayoutHandler.SetVirtualView(IView view)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ViewHandler`2[[Microsoft.Maui.ILayout, Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[Microsoft.Maui.Platform.LayoutView, Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].SetVirtualView(IElement view)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Element.SetHandler(IElementHandler newHandler)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Element.set_Handler(IElementHandler value)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.VisualElement.Microsoft.Maui.IElement.set_Handler(IElementHandler value)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ElementExtensions.ToHandler(IElement view, IMauiContext context)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ElementExtensions.ToPlatform(IElement view, IMauiContext context)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ScrollViewHandler.UpdateContentView(IScrollView scrollView, IScrollViewHandler handler)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ScrollViewHandler.MapContent(IScrollViewHandler handler, IScrollView scrollView)
   at Microsoft.Maui.PropertyMapper`2.<>c__DisplayClass5_0[[Microsoft.Maui.IScrollView, Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.IScrollViewHandler, Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].<Add>b__0(IElementHandler h, IElement v)
   at Microsoft.Maui.PropertyMapper.UpdatePropertyCore(String key, IElementHandler viewHandler, IElement virtualView)
   at Microsoft.Maui.PropertyMapper.UpdateProperties(IElementHandler viewHandler, IElement virtualView)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ElementHandler.SetVirtualView(IElement view)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ViewHandler`2[[Microsoft.Maui.IScrollView, Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[UIKit.UIScrollView, Microsoft.iOS, Version=16.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=84e04ff9cfb79065]].SetVirtualView(IView view)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ViewHandler`2[[Microsoft.Maui.IScrollView, Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[UIKit.UIScrollView, Microsoft.iOS, Version=16.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=84e04ff9cfb79065]].SetVirtualView(IElement view)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Element.SetHandler(IElementHandler newHandler)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Element.set_Handler(IElementHandler value)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.VisualElement.Microsoft.Maui.IElement.set_Handler(IElementHandler value)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ElementExtensions.ToHandler(IElement view, IMauiContext context)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ElementExtensions.ToPlatform(IElement view, IMauiContext context)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ContentViewHandler.UpdateContent(IContentViewHandler handler)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ContentViewHandler.MapContent(IContentViewHandler handler, IContentView page)
   at Microsoft.Maui.PropertyMapper`2.<>c__DisplayClass5_0[[Microsoft.Maui.IContentView, Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.IContentViewHandler, Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].<Add>b__0(IElementHandler h, IElement v)
   at Microsoft.Maui.PropertyMapper.UpdatePropertyCore(String key, IElementHandler viewHandler, IElement virtualView)
   at Microsoft.Maui.PropertyMapper.UpdateProperties(IElementHandler viewHandler, IElement virtualView)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ElementHandler.SetVirtualView(IElement view)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ViewHandler`2[[Microsoft.Maui.IContentView, Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ContentView, Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].SetVirtualView(IView view)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ContentViewHandler.SetVirtualView(IView view)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ViewHandler`2[[Microsoft.Maui.IContentView, Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ContentView, Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].SetVirtualView(IElement view)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Element.SetHandler(IElementHandler newHandler)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Element.set_Handler(IElementHandler value)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.VisualElement.Microsoft.Maui.IElement.set_Handler(IElementHandler value)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ElementExtensions.ToHandler(IElement view, IMauiContext context)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ViewExtensions.ToHandler(IView view, IMauiContext context)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Platform.Compatibility.ShellSectionRootRenderer.SetPageRenderer(Page page, ShellContent shellContent)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Platform.Compatibility.ShellSectionRootRenderer.LoadRenderers()
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Platform.Compatibility.ShellSectionRootRenderer.ViewDidLoad()
   at UIKit.UIApplication.UIApplicationMain(Int32 argc, String[] argv, IntPtr principalClassName, IntPtr delegateClassName)
   at UIKit.UIApplication.Main(String[] args, Type principalClass, Type delegateClass)
   at CameraTest.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\Maui\annex_apps\CameraTest\CameraTest\Platforms\iOS\Program.cs:line 13}
```

Comment: The simulator does not have camera support.  See https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Maui/issues/133

Comment: @jason I've seen this thread. But people are saying that it crashes also on real device.

Comment: @ThomasCarlton Ok, maybe there is a problem on real devices as well. But running the app on simulator and showing the result has zero value. You need to run the application on real device, and then provide information about the error that happens. (if you get any error at all)